how to search all git repos via command line
There are more than 1k repos in my org projecton GitHub, I want to search for table names in the repos locally. I can use search on the top of console window, but there are hundreds of table names I have to search. Is there any way to perform this search by command line or easier way to search?

Are you searching on github or locally?

on github of my org

First, install GitHub CLI.
Then, gh auth login to log into your GitHub account from command line.
Finally, gh search code table-name --owner=org-name. Replace org-name with the name of your org.
